# JQuery and Perl to display dynamic results on drop down selection

Tags: html, ajax, perl, jquery

I'm currently using Perl CGI to display some internal billing pages at work.  I'm using JQuery as well to add a little 'spunk' to it if you will.

I'm looking to generate/display HTML based on drop down selection by the user.  Now, I can handle this part no problem.  I'm generating table rows/table data on click based on the selection made by the user.

I want to retrieve and display values stored in the database for the corresponding data im displaying on button click, and without refreshing the page of course.

Can someone point me in the right direction?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use an AJAX request to get the data. So, for example, if you have a select with class 'ajax' and you want to display data based on the option selected, you can do something like:

```
$('.ajax').change(function(){
    $.get({'url', { value: this.val() }, function(data){
        // display the data with a .html() or .append() or something
    });
});
```

Replace 'url' with the url of a page that queries the database using the value that you send it.